# Why isn't my user defined exception being handled properly?

Tags: python

I'm wondering a user defined exception I've raised in my python program from within a class isn't being handled by the correct exception handler within my `main()`.  Say I have a class:

```
class Pdbalog:
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, logtype):
        if logtype == 1 or logtype == 2:
            # These are valid
            self.logtypeV = logtype
            ...<continue processing>
        else:
            # Invalid
            raise Exception("Invalid Logtype")
```

My `main` looks like:

```
from pdbalog import *
def main():
    try:
        mylog = Pdbalog(10)
        ...<other code here>

    except "Invalid Logtype":
        print('Exiting...')
    except:
        print('Unhandled exception')
        raise
```

I would expect the when `main` is run that the line where I instantiate the `Pdbalog` object would raise an exception (`Exception("Invalid Logtype")`) and the exception handler in main (`except "Invalid Logtype"`) would print the output string `"Exiting..."`.  However, it does not.  It is being handled by the unhandled exception handler.  What ends up happening is the  string `"Unhandled exception"` is being output.  Why isn't the

```
    except "Invalid Logtype":
```

handling the exception?

I am using an old version of python (2.4).

Comment: I think you forgot adding `try:` in `main()`, I added. As I am also Python learner. Please check my edit.... and congrats for 1K :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
class InvalidLogType(Exception):
   pass
```

then

```
raise InvalidLogType()
```

then

```
except InvalidLogType:
   etc
```

Comment: `True`. (8 more to go)

Comment: So then are you saying that I have to define a new class for every custom exception I want to create?  What I'd like to do is create a "MyException" class with all of the exceptions defined for the app.  Is that possible?

Comment: You can, but creating a class for each one is the normal way things are done in lots of languages (Python, Java, C# etc). Why not? If you don't want to catch them then you can just include messages as you have been doing, but if you do want to catch them then you have to write your own handling to match the strings. That's even worse as the language has no way of checking that you're looking for the correct strings. What if you changed a message in the future? Using custom classes you can deal with this situation.

Answer (score 9):

`Exception("Invalid Logtype")` is still just an `Exception`, just now with an error message. `"Invalid Logtype"` isn't an error, just a `str`, so you can't catch it.

Try:

```
class InvalidLogtype(Exception): pass

try:
    raise InvalidLogType
except InvalidLogType:
    pass
```

Note that you can catch based on error messages by doing

```
except Exception, e:
    if e.args == ("Invalid Logtype",):
        ...

    else:
        raise
```

Comment: `<pedantry>` Actually, you *can* raise and catch strings as exceptions in Python 2.4 (and in Python 2.5, though it'll give you a DeprecationWarning)`</pedantry>`

Comment: Also note that the `except Exception as e` syntax won't work in Python 2.4.

Comment: @MarkDickinson it should be as `except Exception, e:` **?** Is Error is also a class ?

Comment: It seems I can get it to work by defining each user defined exception as a class (class myExcept(Exception): pass).  However, if I try to accept arguments (like a text string), then it does not work.  I would think I should be able to set any attribute of the exception class and it should work.

Comment: I don't have Python 2.4. If you want me to help you should give full tracebacks and attempts. You can edit your post if need be.